# Menus still enabled after EnableWindow(False)

Tags: .net, pinvoke

In our application, we have a business requirement to open a .NET form from a VB6 COM component. The child form should essentially work like ShowDialog() would as far as the VB6 application is concerned, but the .NET application should remain unlocked.

To handle this, I used Show(IWin32Window) overload + EnableWindow(hwnd, False) methods to set the parent of the .NET form and disable the owner VB6 form.

However, I'm having two issues:

1. The menus are still partially enabled for some reason. I can't click on a menu, but the ALT shortcuts are still working. For example, I can open the File menu with ALT+F and arrow down to the "Close" menu item to close the screen. Everything else is correctly disabled (i.e., I can't click on any of the menus/controls or type anything anywhere). Do I need to do something else to disable the menu shortcuts?
2. I can still click on the VB6 form. When you use ShowDialog(), the owner form flashes a couple of times and resets the focus to the child form, but this is not happening with EnableWindow. Is there another PInvoke call I can make to fake the ShowDialog() functionality? Is there a way to keep focus on the .NET window whenever the VB6 window gets focus?

The code:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll")>
Public Shared Function EnableWindow(hwnd As IntPtr, bEnable As Boolean) As Boolean
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Private Shared Function GetForegroundWindow() As IntPtr
End Function

Public Class WindowWrapper
    Implements IWin32Window

    Private _handle As IntPtr

    Public Sub New(handle As IntPtr)
        _handle = handle
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Handle As System.IntPtr Implements IWin32Window.Handle
        Get
            Return _handle
        End Get
    End Property
End Class

Dim foregroundWindowId As IntPtr = GetForegroundWindow()
Dim vb6Process As Process = Process.GetProcessById(VB6ProcessId)
Dim ownerWindow As WindowWrapper = New WindowWrapper(foregroundWindowId)

EnableWindow(foregroundWindowId, False)
Show(ownerWindow)
```